# Load external javascript after click a button

Tags: javascript

I want to load a javascript from an external source on my site, after clicking on a button.

I tried the following solution. Java script code, which is executed after clicking on the button:

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "scrSource";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

So now I can see the javaScript in my head, but it was not executed.

So when I load my external script with the normal way (when the page is loading) in the header, it loads a few other java script sources.

But with my solution (load file after clicking a button), I only put it in the head and no further action is happening.

Do someone have any ideas how I can solve this problem? (and I´m not allowed to use jQuery, only java script)

Comment: Check your first line `varscript=document.createElement("script");` , here you just need to give a white space between `var` and `script`. 

Comment: In your external javascript, put `debugger` in a code where it loads other scripts, and check what happens

Comment: You can use dynamic imports. `import(scriptSrc).then(doSome)`.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no, there is no error. I think the problem is, that the external java script is only appended to the head an not executed.

Comment: add `script.async = true;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loadScript(url, callback){

var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState){  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                script.readyState == "complete"){
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {  //Others
    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    };
}

script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
loadScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/faker.min.js", function(){
//initialization code
alert('loaded: ' + faker.name.findName());
});
```

A simple Google search of "Load external javascript" returns this [link](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/). The function you see it is from there. It's and old one but it works.
I use [Faker.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Faker) to generate random data as confirmation that the library loaded is ready to be used.

It handles onreadystatechange/onload so you can define a callback to start using the library you've just downloaded.